# Facebook like button adds query strin to the url

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

i am implementing the facebook like button, and specified for it the url to like,
when i click on the LIKE button, in facebook i saw the correct page the liked, but when i click on the link there
the link is what is specified in the code with some odd facebook querystring appended.

for exmpl:
the page that i like is
http://www.mydomain.com/path/to/the/page

when i clicked on the liked link in facebook, the url is:
http://www.mydomain.com/path/to/the/page**?fb_action_ids=#####&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map={"###"%###}&action_type_map={"###"%3A"og.likes"}&action_ref_map=[]**

and the page is not loaded correctly, is this is a facebook fault?

Answer (score 1):

Use the xfbml or html5 version of social plugin and include in your metatag this

```
<meta property="og:url" content="...." />
```

Comment: This solves the issue for making sure that all likes are counted for the same URL regardless of query strings, but I am working on a client's site over which I have no control, which fails when the query string is appended. It means that people can't click on the link from a user's FB wall. It would be nice to be able to remove the query string if necessary.

Comment: xfbml + metatag og:url solve the problem. Your post in FB wall still has the query string but when you click you will redirect to the url specified in the metatag. If you don't have control of the content of the page i don't think you can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook adds various parameters to the URL so you can track where the visits are coming from etc. Its probably your page that doesn't work with these parameters, rather than facebook. Ideally, you page should just ignore these parameters if you don't need them.

Comment: its not, those parameters are used by facebook... for the l.php file that redirects from facbook

Comment: Facebook still adds those URLs on to the final URL. All OpenGraph actions have this information in the URL, but it's for tracking purposes. Fix your site / page to ignore these.

Comment: It's not possible to "ignore" this as this query messes up ALL url like/share services. If you have 1000 likes on xyz.com, then you have 0 (!) likes on xyz.com/?test123

Comment: That's correct. Technically `xyz.com` is different to `xyz.com/?test123`. You shouldn't be using the URL in the browser for the Like button, you should define the URL for the page using OpenGraph tags.

Comment: How?
iam using the iframe version of the code, and there is an param for the url, so i use it. there is alternative way?

Comment: Use the HTML5 version of the plugin and set the URL for the Like Button to the page URL and use OpenGraph tags on the page, namely `og:url`.

Comment: it tried, and its make the same thing, appends some query string to the url! :|

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by defining the URL in the fb:like button as well as in the og:url.

```
<fb:like href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourfullurl.html" send="true" layout="button_count" width="300" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Now regardless of the parameters sent back from FB it seems to honor the count.

Answer (score 0):

We can remove/strip the appended query string with the help of .htaccess file. 
Place the code mentioned below in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fb_action_ids=.*$
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fb_comment_id=.*$
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

This will do the trick :)